# navigator,vibrate - html5

Tags: javascript, html5

Estou desenvolvendo um chat em html5, para minha empresa, e estou usando a biblioteca navigator.vibrate para ativar o modo de vibração do celular. Tudo funciona quando eu estou com o foco na tab do browser com a aplicação. O problema que tenho é quando o celular está no modo sleep(turn off) a vibração não funciona.
Tenho como ativar isso pelo javascript?

Muito obrigado!

Lenine De Maria

Comment: Creio que isso seja impossível, visto que o JS não tem total controle sobre o navegador, imagine sobre o hardware.

Comment: OkI Obrigado pelo rápido retorno. Então pelo que entendi, não existe uma forma de ativar a vibração no celular quando está no modo sleep pelo js, certo? Sera que existe alguma biblioteca do html5 que libera a vibração no modo sleep?
Sei que por uma app, muda-se a segurança assim: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
Obrigado Sam!